# C++, pointer to class static member are realy pointers?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, static, member

I have a typedef of a pointer to class member function:

```
typedef int (ClassA::*FunctionPointerType) (bool buy, const QVector<int>& varIdV);
```

And i declare a static array of this inside a class :
in .h file :

`static vector<FunctionPointerType> m_functionPointerV;`

Everything works well and i can assign my functions, and later call them.
My question is :
This is really a vector of pointers ? I mean, in time we create this vector still there not exist any object.

In case of pointers to class static data members, which can be accessed later with a object, this pointers to class do not point to any place in memory. So there are pointers or there are like a distance to a given object memory location ?

Thanks for any answer. Daniel

Comment: Function pointers - both member and non-member point directly to the instructions of those functions. They are unrelated to any objects, that is why you have to supply `this` object manually.

Comment: These are pointers to members which are **not** static

Comment: *this pointers to class do not point to any place in memory* - where do you think instructions to be executed are stored? **In the memory**. It's just a separate memory area from where the data is stored , to keep it safer. Pointer to function (member or not) points to the instructions that are to be executed when the function is called.

Comment: Class member functions (both static and non-static) could exists even if no objects of this class were ever created. They are required to be available if ODR-used somewhere, and taking a function address is such a case.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "Pointer to function (member or not) points to the instructions" [this is false](https://godbolt.org/z/bvbGhTshc).

Comment: Pointers to static class members (data or function, doesn't matter) are regular pointers, identical to pointers to free variables/functions. Pointers to **non** static class members (data or function, doesn't matter) are **not** regular pointers. They are not compatible with regular pointers and cannot be used the same way.

Comment: Thanks  n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. You answer my question. So, if there are non static class members, and we use class member pointers to point this members as variables, then this not are regular pointers. How we can call them ? Which kind of integer is this kind of pointers value ? What means ?

Comment: @DanielPol since this is a pointer to a member function, it usually contains a pointer to the function's code, just like a pointer to a non-member function. It might also contain a base class offset.